# Performing side effects during computation only once in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say we want a collection of values that are computed on demand (the computation has some side effects), and not recomputed again when you access them again.

The following two naive approaches will not work:

```hs
Prelude> let f x = print x >> return x
Prelude> let a = map f "abc"
Prelude> :t a
a :: [IO Char]
Prelude> head a
'a'
'a'
Prelude> head a
'a'
'a'
```

```hs
Prelude> let b = mapM f "abc"
Prelude> :t b
b :: IO [Char]
Prelude> fmap head b
'a'
'b'
'c'
'a'
Prelude> fmap head b
'a'
'b'
'c'
'a'
```

How do I do it correctly? As of now, I don't even understand what type the collection should have.

Comment: If done as above it looks like it would violate referential transparency. I'd use a `mkOnce :: IO (IO Char)` instead, so that we can do `once <- mkOnce` and then `once :: IO Char` will have side effects only the first time it's used. You will need to use some `IOVar (Maybe Char)` to cache the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a small library to cache values using an `IORef`. The function `cache` below transforms an `IO a` into another `IO a` which will only perform the side effects once, and return the cached value the next times it is executed.

```
import Data.IORef

cache :: IO a -> IO (IO a)
cache action = do
   v <- newIORef Nothing
   return $ do
      x <- readIORef v
      case x of
         Nothing -> do 
            res <- action
            writeIORef v $ Just res
            return res
         Just res -> return res
```

This is your function:

```
f :: Char -> IO Char
f x = print x >> return x
```

Here's a small example showing how to use `cache`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   acts <- mapM (cache . f) "abc"
   -- here we have acts :: [IO Char]
   putStrLn "1st: "
   head acts               -- prints 'a'
   putStrLn "2nd: " 
   head acts               -- prints nothing
   putStrLn "3rd: "
   head acts               -- prints nothing
   return ()
```

Only the first call prints `'a'` on screen.

Comment: ...and is available on Hackage: [1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-memoize-1.1.1.0/docs/System-IO-Memoize.html) [2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/once-0.4/docs/Control-Once.html).

Answer (score 3):

### Slightly unorthodox solution:

```
 λ> 
 λ> import System.IO.Unsafe
 λ> 
 λ> let { cache2 :: IO a -> IO a ; cache2 act = return (unsafePerformIO act) }
 λ> 
 λ> :t cache2
cache2 :: IO a -> IO a
 λ> 
 λ> let f x = print x >> return x
 λ> let a = map f "abc"
 λ>
 λ> :t a
a :: [IO Char]
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> a2 = map cache2 a
 λ> 
 λ> :t a2
a2 :: [IO Char]
 λ>
```

Testing:

```
 λ> 
 λ> head a2
'a'
'a'
 λ> 
 λ> head a2
'a'
 λ> 
 λ> head a2
'a'
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> a2s = sequence a2
 λ> 
 λ> :t a2s
a2s :: IO [Char]
 λ> 
 λ> a2s
"a'b'
b'c'
c"
 λ> 
 λ> a2s
"abc"
 λ>
```

**Explanation:** It is occasionally claimed that function [unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO)  offers a way to *extract* a value from the IO monad. The (sometimes omitted) catch is: how does the Haskell runtime system preserve [referential transparency](https://wiki.haskell.org/Referential_transparency) then ? well, simply by running the underlying computation just once, saving the result and **discarding** possible side effects of running the computation several times.

### Edit:

As mentioned by Jon Purdy in the comments, in a general multithreaded context function [unsafeInterleaveIO :: IO a -> IO a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO) has to be preferred to `unsafePerformIO`. See the documentation for details.

Comment: It's not quite what I wanted, but still, thanks you for posting it, it's a nice alternative to the IORef solution, suitable for playing around in the REPL.

Comment: `unsafeInterleaveIO` would be more appropriate here than `unsafePerformIO`, since it guarantees that the `IO` action is performed at most once, and only on a single thread, which `unsafePerformIO` does not.